# Cannot return View() with varying parameters in C# MVC - Ajax Issues updating page content

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So basically, i'm building a calendar where people can add their meetings by clicking on cells and sending data through an Ajax request. 
This part already works well, but I cannot figure out how to pass the right parameters to the Index() View.

**EDIT:**
My problem now lies in the Ajax function returning the result to the page. I am trying to do in jQuery Ajax the equivalent of the MVC Ajax option **UpdateTargetId** but I cannot figure an adequate way of doing so.

My current Ajax function:

```
function AjaxAddRDV() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Agenda/AddRDV",
        async: "true",
        type: "GET",
        data: { "jour": rdvjour.val(), "mois": rdvmois.val(), "annee": rdvannee.val(), "text": rdvtext.val() },
        success: function (result) {

            $(".cal-container").html(result);  // This gives me the right result but my click events do not work anymore

            /*if (data && data.successUrl) {
                window.location.href = data.successUrl;
            }*/ this reloads the page, which I am trying to avoid
        }

    });
}
```

**Note:** My HTML takes data from the ViewModel and creates a table using the Month and Year passed to the model, given the right parameters it never fails.

```
public ActionResult Index(int annee = 0, int mois = 0)
{
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        if (annee == 0) annee = date.Year;
        if (mois == 0) mois = date.Month;

        AgendaViewModel Agendata = CreateAgendaViewModel(annee, mois);

        if (dal.GetFirstDay(annee, mois) == 0)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View(Agendata);
}
```

This method gets fired when Ajax adds a new appointment:
// **I edited it from the original question**

> ```
>    public ActionResult AddRDV(int jour, int mois, int annee, string text)
>     {
>         AgendaViewModel Agendata = new AgendaViewModel();
>         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
>         {
>             dal.SetRdv(jour, mois, annee, text);
>             Agendata = CreateAgendaViewModel(annee, mois);
>         }
>         return PartialView("Calendrier", Agendata);
>     }
> ```

The HTML i'm trying to update is the following:

> 

```
@model DASIWelcome.ViewModels.AgendaViewModel
 (...)
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="prevmonth" class="switchmonth">←</div>
        <div class="cal-container">

            @Html.Partial("Calendrier",Model)
        </div>
        <div id="nextmonth" class="switchmonth">→</div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

I'm trying to get the @Html.Partial updated every time I send the Ajax request.

**The final objective** is to have an Ajax function that refreshes the calendar for the current month by default, and that will return the same calendar with custom parameters if the month is changed, if a new appointment is added, etc.

I've started C# MVC quite recently, but I've spent the whole day trying to work around this, and I cannot find a solution that is not very ugly and unrecommended...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Things I've tried:**

- Building a second Index Method with parameters - Loading fails saying is it ambiguous
- Finding out which method called index in the first place to fork between actions - Didn't work + was considered an ugly solution everywhere I looked
- Crying

---

**The previous issue has been resolved, here are the points where I was struggling and that did not allow me to go forward:**

- The click function was not working on dynamically created elements, thus only worked once per page loading.
- At first I could not get the jQuery Ajax function to refresh my table the same way that the MVC Ajax UpdateTargetId function would.

Here is how I fixed the click event:

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".week td", function(){
```

What I struggled to understand with the on() function was that the *first selector* $("#wrapper") has to be **static**, and the *second selector* ".week td" is the selector for the **dynamically** created elements.

Since I was trying to fix the wrong thing, I did manage to find the equivalent between MVC Ajax UpdateTargetId and jQuery Ajax:
**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Agenda/AddRDV",
            async: "true",
            type: "GET",
            data: { "jour": rdvjour.val(), "mois": rdvmois.val(), "annee": rdvannee.val(), "text": rdvtext.val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#cal-container").html(result);
            }
        });
```

**MVC Ajax:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddRDV", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "GET",
//InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
UpdateTargetId = "cal-container",
OnComplete = "rdvdialog.dialog('close')"
}))
{
    <label for="rdvannee">Année</label>
    <label for="rdvmois">Mois</label>
    <label for="rdvjour">Jour</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="annee" id="rdvannee" maxlength="4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="mois" id="rdvmois" maxlength="2" size="2" />
    <input type="text" name="jour" id="rdvjour" maxlength="2" size="2" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="rdvtext">Titre</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" maxlength="250" />
    <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
}
```

Special thanks to *dlght* who pointed me in the right direction and offered me a few useful alternatives!

Comment: I just realized my whole page reloaded because of the Ajax complete function: [ http://d.pr/i/DSb2 ]
However I could not figure how to reload my page without using the load function...

Comment: i have just editted my answer, but you haven't looked i guess :D remove the complete function and use the success i suggested

Comment: It did allow me to refresh the page, but I'm trying to only update the table. 

I can do something that works, BUT my click event only fires once and then I can't click anywhere to open the dialog. 

I know this is due to the html elements being newly created, but even using ".on('click', function(){.... "
The click event is not firing...

I really did not expect this to be that hard to accomplish...

Comment: Here's my current click function (I've tried many ones without success)

[ http://d.pr/i/1cTB8 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "ChangeMonth" method is the same as the Index method, but with parameters.Just reload the Index, when the user change the calendar.I would even suggest you to make a function that takes care of your ViewModel creation so you can reuse the model in other ActionMethods if you need it:

```
public AgendaViewModel CreateAgendaViewModel(int annee, int mois)
{
            AgendaViewModel agendata = new AgendaViewModel();

            agendata.ListRDV = dal.GetListRDV(mois, annee); //Loads the list of appointments for the chosen month
            agendata.FirstDay = dal.GetFirstDay(annee, mois);
            agendata.MonthLength = dal.GetMonthLength(annee, mois);
            agendata.MonthName = dal.GetMonthName(mois) + " " + annee.ToString();
            agendata.Mois = mois;
            agendata.Annee = annee;

            return agendata;
}

public ActionResult Index(int annee = 0, int mois = 0)
{
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        if(annee == 0) annee = date.Year; // if not set initialize with default year
        if(mois == 0)  mois = date.Month; // if not set initialize with default month

        AgendaViewModel Agendata = CreateAgendaViewModel(annee, mois);
        if (dal.GetFirstDay(annee, mois) == 0)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View(Agendata); 
    }
```

In the add method now you can redirect to the index with the selected month and year:

```
public ActionResult AddRDV(int jour, int mois, int annee, string text)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            dal.SetRdv(jour, mois, annee, text);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { annee = annee, mois = mois });
}
```

Another note - please write your code in english. Your code would be so much more readable if you name your parameters and variables in English not only for you, but for the other people that might look at your code.

Hope this helps ;]

EDIT:

There are two ways to redirect from ajax function:
1) If there is no other functionality on the page you can reload the whole page by passing Json result with the URL route in the success:

```
public JsonResult AddRDV(int jour, int mois, int annee, string text)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            dal.SetRdv(jour, mois, annee, text);
        }
        var successUrl = Url.Action("Index", new { annee = annee, mois = mois });
        return Json(new {successUrl = successUrl});
}

Then in your ajax you do redirect to the index page:
$.ajax({ ...,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data && data.successUrl){
            window.location.href = data.successUrl;
        }
    }
});
```

2) You can change your logic so that the Calendar is created in partial view loaded inside the page. Then you can reload just the partial view by calling ajax that reloads the wrapper of the calendar - you can check an example of this [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/walkthrough-updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: I just implemented what you suggested, it's better structured, but the SAME glitch happens, this has to do with how MVC renders HTML pages, no matter what I do, EVERYTIME I use the AddRDV function, the whole thing goes as planned, and then BANG, the Index method reloads with default parameters.

Comment: Sorry about the french parameters, I'm writing this code for people who barely understand english...

Comment: please provide more code. Let me see how you call the add func. If you call it and then reload the page the index would reload with default parameters. its ok about the french, its just a good practice

Comment: OMG 
I found why it reloads, the Ajax function reloads the index, BUT, I struggled with this as well and I could not figure how to reload the table without doing it in the first place... I feel pretty stuck
[http://d.pr/i/DSb2 ]

Comment: It does work!!
Thank you very much!

However, it reloads the whole page, which is what I was trying to avoid. It's gonna do the job for now, but i'll try to implement your solution #2, as I want the calendar to ultimately be constantly refreshing its content seamlessly.

Comment: I've actually successfully done it using their method before, but it requires the usage of Ajax.BeginForm with the option "new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "######"}

The target ID does get updated and it works as intended, but is there a way to replace the **UpdateTargetId** property when doing jQuery Ajax???

This would solve all my problems...

Comment: I solved it, by using $(selectorNOTdinamicallycreated).on("click","childelement selector", function(){....   

I'm marking it as solved by you and editing my original question. 

Thanks a thousand times for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to accomplish several things from the same method (Index).

**Option 1**

You receive a `FormCollection` object in your `Index` when data is posted. So, whatever is posted can be retrieved in the form collection.  Then, your code can understand what data is received and dispatch correctly to the right method.

The code would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var myValue = formCollection["myvalue"];
}
```

**Option 2**

The second option is to use and call different methods but use the same `View()`.  The output of the view would look like this:

```
public ActionResult OtherAction(string param1)
{
    var model = this.GenerateModel(param1);

    // Use the index View (assuming the controller is called Calendar
    return View("Calendar/Index", model );
}
```

The problem with the second option (that you tried in your question) is that it does too many things. I think the date should be a parameter.  You should also build your model in a separate function.  That way, it will be easier to send the right parameters to your "model generator" and get the expected output.

Crying won't help fixing your code... but it may ease your pain. ;-)